# Interaction objects three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wanted to ask a question on the topic of 'interaction object...'. Any object that has obj.position.x/.z , it would be good to make the interaction with the map object.
Map - `map.vertices[f].x/.z` , while moving obj how best to implement the assignment and checking the new position obj position on the map?
I tried to make a comparison of positions, `if(obj.x === map [id].x) return id;`
But this method is not very good.
I will be glad to receive a hint to help implement this feature.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you want some kind of physics library for collision detection?

Comment: No I do not need a library with physics. I need to implement a contact object (obj) to the card (PlaneGeometry). How best to do it?

Comment: What would be accurate. I need to hint at how best to implement:
The collision object and maps